# PHP Version Upgrade Caused Problems With Class Constructors

Tags: php, class, constructor

I just upgraded my PHP version from `v5.3.1` to `v5.3.9`. Suddenly class constructors started not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using constructors with Class name instead of `__construct()` keyword. See the behaviour change in v5.3.3 here:

http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-07-22-2

Use `__construct()` and you should be fine.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Note that this behaviour only changed back for namespaced classes.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I was using namespaces and constructor names equal to class names. I tried to accept the answer but it says i need to wait a few more minutes. I'm new to this site. Sorry if i'm missing something.

Comment: @Henry Adams: Nice to hear that your problem is solved. You need to wait for a while before accepting an answer at the beginning stages. That's normal.