# class construction must work in different php versions

Tags: php, class, constructor, versioning

One of our user groups created and has been maintaining a site on godaddy.com. The person who made it left, users asked MIS for help, and I was asked to make changes. It must remain on godaddy.com until we figure out how best to move the application to our own servers.

To make a test environment I downloaded everything to my workstation, enabled IIS, and installed PHP and MySQL. The needed changes were made. Users approved the changes. Unfortunately one of the files does not work on godaddy.com. I'm asking for help because I have PHP experience, but haven't worked much with classes.

Originally the code had:

```
private static $DB_HOSTs = 'xxxxxxx';
```

I changed it to:

```
private static $DB_HOSTs;
public function __construct() {
    $this->DB_HOSTs = (strtoupper($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])=='D444L40334') ? 'localhost:3306' : 'xxxxxxxx';
```

I read about "private static" to find variables cannot be set using external variables and it is necessary to use the __construct() method. After making this change it worked correctly on my machine. I thought this might be a versioning problem and the following stackoverflow question [PHP Version Upgrade Caused Problems With Class Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094910/php-version-upgrade-caused-problems-with-class-constructors) confirms that.

I need to have the same code on both my workstation and the godaddy.com site. I do not change files going from test to production with different files between the two. Instead I make the code dynamic. What change do I need to make in this case? My workstation PHP version is 5.3.28 and godaddy.com is 5.2.17. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between 5.2.x and 5.3.x

A lot of the changes are made in the object oriented side of php.

I wont mention how extremely outdated 5.2.x is.

You can look at this to see the changes.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php

Comment: I looked at that already. The answer doesn't tell me what I need to change. I'm hoping someone with version experience can tell me what to change in the code. an error does not occur where $DB_HOSTs is assigned, but further down where it's used, and the value is blank because __construct() is not called.

Comment: In php 5.2 __construct didn't exist. PHP 5.2 classes don't have a constructor.

Comment: This was an easy fix. If someone guesses what I did and posts I will select that as the answer. I don't want to post the answer myself.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :)